# how to pass StringArrayType to Jetpack Compose Navigation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to pass an array of strings in the navigation, but I don’t quite understand how to do it, with simple types I use the string builder.

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String) {
    object PrivacyPolicyScreen: Screen("privacy_policy_screen")
    object DownloadImageScreen: Screen("download_image_screen")
    object DrawingScreen: Screen("drawing_screen")
    object GenerationResultScreen: Screen("generation_result_screen")
    fun withArgs(vararg args: String) : String{
        return buildString {
            append(route)
            args.forEach {arg ->
                append("/$arg")
            }
        }
    }
}

composable(route = Screen.GenerationResultScreen.route, arguments = listOf(
            navArgument("urls") {
                type = NavType.StringArrayType
            }
        )) {entry ->
            GenerationResultScreen(navController = navController, urls = entry.arguments?.getStringArray("urls"))
}
```

Comment: I think you should use shared ViewModel.

Comment: The first option is to revisit if you can avoid using arrays for navigation as navigation arguments should be small. If not possible, you need to serialize and use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send anything more advanced than basic strings/ints/things that fit in a url, the official Jetpack Compose Navigation is not great.

One idea is that you can pass an id and then the new screen can get the data (in this case the urls) from a common place: SharedPreferences, a singleton etc.

If you want more flexibility in what you can pass I would recommend another navigation library, such as https://github.com/olshevski/compose-navigation-reimagined.

This lets you pass anything you want between screens as long as it is Parcelable.